# Get error status from invoked make targets

Tags: bash, makefile

I have makefile setup where multiple modules are being built:

```
foo:
  <command to build foo>

bar:
  <command to build bar>

baz:
  <command to build baz>

deploy: pre_check foo bar baz display_result
```

When I call `make deploy`, it first calls `pre_check` and then depends on `foo`, `bar` and `baz`, so if needed it builds them in sequence. This works fine.
After the build is done I want to display the result of the build (e.g. to send a notification to some team collaboration tool like Slack).

How can I define the `display_result` target so that it knows whether all the targets so far succeeded or failed (and which target failed), so that it can display a suitable status message (such as "success" or "failure: `bar` failed")?

I use GNU Make 4.1 with Bash on Ubuntu.

Comment: You can get the overall status of the make as $? in your bash script. If you want to know which element of the make failed you generally end up capturing and parsing the make text output for "clues", if you don't simply paste the whole output to the error long. Note that make doesn't generally see your requested targets as specific steps to be performed, and only tends to tell you about the steps that do actual work.

Answer (score 0):

When you run 'make deploy' without any options, targets are processed sequentailly, and failure in one target will prevent the make from moving to the next target.

Few exceptions to the rule:
* When asked for for parallel build ('make -j ...') make will start processing target in parallel, so it's possible that it will try to two (or more) targets at the same time.
* With '-k', make it not stop after the first failure, so that display_result will be build, regardless of success in previous steps.

One possible workaround, add explicit dependecies between display_result and the steps that are required before it can be run:

```
display_result: pre_check foo ...
```